# C# fault exception: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I am trying to run the below mentioned piece of code, but it throws an error after execution saying " Index was outside the bounds of the array". I am unable to trace the issue, any leads would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Data = new objData[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];


for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Data[i] = new objData();

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["VALUE"] != DBNull.Value)
        Data[i].Value = float.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["VALUE"].ToString());

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DATE"] != DBNull.Value)
        Data[i].Date = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DATE"].ToString());
}
```

ds.Dispose();

Comment: where is the `Data` defined ?

Comment: What do you mean by unable to trace the issue? You can't attach a debugger to the code?

Comment: Did you initialize `Data` with something like `objData[] Data = new objData[/* any integer value*/]`

Comment: I have initialized Data as defined by @Sameer Anand before starting the for loop. Chris, I did attach the debugger, the complete array is being populated but it throws an error after the loop.

Comment: after the loop?, does it execute some statement after the loop and throws the error?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with Data array. Over here you are just assigning new objData to a Data[i] reference which in not declared. Probably, you should declare Data array as

```
objData[] Data=new objData[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count]
```

Comment: maybe there is no table in the dataset :)

Comment: The error Index was outside the bounds of the array, indicates there is table in the data set. Its an array error :)

Comment: @Haris, I initialized the object as described by you at the start of the for loop.

Comment: If there is no table in the dataset, it will also throw an `IndexOutOfRange` exception.

Comment: @Selman22, there is a table in the dataset being populated using an SQL query and the data is being copied to the array in the for loop, but when I dispose the dataset using `ds.Dispose()` I get the exception.

Comment: @user3437533 So, you `Dispose` the dataset before the `for` loop?

Comment: @Selman22, no after the for loop, I have edited the code in my question.

Comment: you should debug your program and find the exact line that the error occurs.